# Critical point of a function of two variables $f(x,y)=3x^4 -4x^2y+y^2$: minimum, maximum or saddle?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

If $f(x,y)=3x^4 -4x^2y+y^2$ then :

a)$(0,0)$ is local max point

b)$(0,0)$ is local min point

c)$(0,0)$ is saddle point

d) none

I think we find critical points so we must find all point of equation $\nabla f =0$ then $(0,0)$ is critical point but $f_{x,x} = f_{y,y} =f_{x,y}=0$ now  we can't use  this test.

Comment: "now we can't use this test."  Why not?

Comment: Because $f_{x,x} = f_{y,y} =f_{x,y}=0$  then $f_{x,x} f_{y,y} -{f_{x,y}}^2 =0$

Comment: what about the second derivatives ? ;-)

Comment: The problem is that $f_{xx}  f_{yy} -f_{x,y}^2=0$   and so second derivatives is inconclusive here. Perhaps a 3D graph from an online graphing tool might give some clues? I did this one: http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/graph3d/

Comment: Look at the behaviour as $x \to 0$  along any line $y=\lambda x$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to check that second derivatives are zero at $(0,0)$, so it is a [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point).

We may notice that 
$$f(x,y)=(2x^2-y)^2-x^4=(2x^2-y)^2-(x^2)^2=(x^2-y)(3x^2-y).$$
We immediately see that for $y=x^2$ or $y=3x^2$ we have $f(x,y)=0$, which means that it cannot be *strict* local minimum/maximum.

If we write $f(x,y)$ in this form it also suggests to look how the function behaves along other curves of the form $y=kx^2$. (Notice that each such curve goes through $(0,0)$).

- For $y=2x^2$ we get $f(x,y)=-x^4\le 0$. (And the inequality is strict if $x\ne 0$.)
- For $y=4x^2$ we get $f(x,y)=3x^4\ge 0$. (And the inequality is strict if $x\ne 0$.)

So it is not an extremum, which means that it is a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point).

---

Notice that from the expression $f(x,y)=(x^2-y)(3x^2-y)$ we can also easily see where the function has positive/negative answer. (This is also says us that it is not an extremum. This argument was used in Emilio Novati's answer.)

We may also notice that $f(x,y)=g(x^2,y)$, where $g(t,y)=3t^2-4ty+y^2$. We could investigate behavior of $g(t,y)$ at $(0,0)$. But it is not immediately clear how this translates to the behavior of $f(x,y)$. (Because we would have to look only on $t\ge0$.)

Answer (score 6):

We know that $f(0,0)=0$.  Now search where $f(x,y)>0$.

We have:
$$
y^2-4x^2y+3x^4>0 
$$
with solution: $x^2<y<3x^2$, so for all neighborhoods of $(0,0)$  the function change sign in the neighborhood and $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: See my reconziliatione.

Comment: Here a numerical experiment (I don't see the minimu): http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3x%5E4-4x%5E2y%2By%5E2%2C+x%3D-0.1..0.1%2C+y%3D-0.1..0.1

Comment: I don't understand that picture. If $y=0$ then $f(x,0)=3x^4$. So there is a local minimum at zero in the $xz$ plane.

Comment: Here is a much better view supporting the local minimum version:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3x%5E4-4x%5E2y%2By%5E2%2C+x%3D-2..2%2C+y%3D0..5

Comment: Yes. I agree ! The contour plot indicate this, but it seems not a minimum for the function.

Comment: So, supposing that you are right, where I'm wrong? I don't see the mistake in my proof :(

Comment: You seem to be right.

Comment: I found the final evidence that you are right. See the behavior of the function along the line $y=2x^2$. Now, $f(x,2x^2)=-9x^4$.

Comment: I see!! so, really, the straight line test is not conclusive :)

Comment: No : (  And this is very enlightening to me. This is why I am her. (Some education...)